# How to use Date Picker in Xceed PropertyGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, propertygrid, xceed, wpf-extended-toolkit

We are using Extended WPF Toolkit in order to implement `PropertyGrid`.

The default date picking control does not seem to be the WPF `DatePicker`, but instead a custom control, if I'm not mistaken.

Usually, we are using `DatePicker` controls in order to select dates. Is it possible to use them, too, for the `PropertyGrid` control? We need this in order to provide a consistent date format of `dd.MM.yyyy` and since this property is a date, time should also not be displayed.

Can this be done using Xceed Property Grid?

```
[Category("General")]
[DisplayName("Date")]
[PropertyOrder(2)]
public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
```

[image: datepicker]

Comment: Sorry I can't understand: do you want to use both the `DatePicker` **and** the custom default control, or just the `DatePicker` (instead of the custom default control)?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how the control is implemented. But in the end, what I need is the date field of the `PropertyGrid` to be date without time and `dd.MM.yyyy` as format. Just like the DatePicker control is. If Xceed uses a custom control is secondary as long as it's the right format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you ask for is not so difficult to achive: Xceed `PropertyGrid` is high customizable and a property editor can be customized by using the [ITypeEditor](https://xceed.com/wp-content/documentation/xceed-toolkit-plus-for-wpf/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit~Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.Editors.ITypeEditor.html) interface and the [Editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.componentmodel.editorattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute.

First of all we need to define a custom editor control:

```
public class DateTimePickerEditor : DateTimePicker, ITypeEditor
{
    public DateTimePickerEditor()
    {
        Format = DateTimeFormat.Custom;
        FormatString = "dd.MM.yyyy";

        TimePickerVisibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        ShowButtonSpinner = false;
        AutoCloseCalendar = true;
    }

    public FrameworkElement ResolveEditor(PropertyItem propertyItem)
    {
        Binding binding = new Binding("Value");
        binding.Source = propertyItem;
        binding.Mode = propertyItem.IsReadOnly ? BindingMode.OneWay : BindingMode.TwoWay;

        BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, ValueProperty, binding);
        return this;
    }
}
```

All the stuff in the constructor are made for obtaining a specific behavior (i.e. no time controls, a specific date format and so on).

Now we need to set the `DateTimePickerEditor` as the default editor for the object property (that in our sample is called "Date"):

```
[Category("General")]
[DisplayName("Date")]
[PropertyOrder(2)]
[Editor(typeof(DateTimePickerEditor), typeof(DateTimePicker))]
public Nullable<DateTime> Date
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Vic. I will try this out when I'm back at work on Monday :)

Comment: What if we don't have access to the property? is there a way to dynamically assign the editor to a given property instead?

Comment: In this case @brianestey you can consider using [EditorTemplateDefinition](https://xceed.com/wp-content/documentation/xceed-toolkit-plus-for-wpf/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit~Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.EditorTemplateDefinition.html). You can find some samples [here](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PropertyGrid)

Comment: This results in a bug for me, the date picker falls back to default after a date selection is made. This happens because I set the date twice in the dates property setter, causing property changed to be fired twice. I do not get this without your code or if I do not set the date twice. I have a way round this, but surely it should be able to handle multiple property changed events in quick succession.

Comment: It is hard to understand your bug @D.Hunt just with a comment. Maybe you can ask a new question. It depends on your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an XAML only solution using editor templates shown at "Custom Editors with DataTemplates":

https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PropertyGrid&referringTitle=Home

Using this approach you aren't cluttering your model-classes with attributes of external libraries.

Your formatted input of DateTime-types can be achieved via:

```
<xctk:PropertyGrid>
    <xctk:PropertyGrid.EditorDefinitions>    
        <xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition>
            <xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition.TargetProperties>
                <xctk:TargetPropertyType Type="{x:Type sys:DateTime}" />
            </xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition.TargetProperties>
            <xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition.EditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <xctk:DateTimePicker Value="{Binding Value}" Format="ShortDate" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition.EditingTemplate>
       </xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition>
   </xctk:PropertyGrid.EditorDefitions>
</xctk:PropertyGrid>
```

With namespace sys defined `xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`

Comment: This doesn't work with DateTime?  (ie. nullable DateTime)